# Testing for $_POST var affects variable even though $_POST should be undefined

Tags: php

I have used for years this method of testing for a $_POST var and assigning a value to $var simultaneously.

Today I ran into a server that seems to be different in its handling of this.

I'm loading the page  http://site.com/foo.php?var=bar   No form post made...  and testing for $_POST var seems to unset my initial assignment

```
$var= $_GET['var'];

echo "var is $var\n";  // correctly echos $_GET['var'] 

if ($var= $_POST['foo']) {
    echo "POST foo seen\n";  // does not fire, condition not met
}

echo "var is $var\n";  // does not echo $_GET['var']
```

When I switched to

```
if (isset($_POST['foo'])) {
    $var = $_POST['foo'];
...
```

I got rid of the unsetting behavior.

So my question is whether this `if ($var= $_POST['foo']) {` is bad form?

Comment: You ask if it's bad form. Both replies essentially say yes and you defend your answer as being intentional and "worked before". Why even ask if you don't want the help?

Comment: Your code works just fine for me: `$_POST['foo'] = '1'; if ($var = $_POST['foo']) echo "POST foo seen\n";`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the assignment operator `=` iinstead of the comparison operator `==`.  Also, note that PHP will throw an `E_STRICT` warning when accessing an undefined array element.  Therefore, the best bet is typically:

$name = trim(isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '');

or for integers:

$age = intval(isset($_POST['age']) ? $_POST['age'] : '');

Comment: I am deliberately using the assignment operator.  The way this functions on every other server I have ever used it on is the equivalent of "If post['foo'] is defined set $var to its value otherwise do nothing"

Comment: To be honest, i don't see the point in assigning the variable in a conditional statement when it is intended to serve a comparision. Can you explain more clear what's the purpose of this?

Comment: The flow here is part of an editing form.  User clicks link to edit and $_GET var is set by this.  Form is populated based on $_GET var.  Form is POSTed and foo MAY be set in form.  Actions are made using conditional regarding whether foo was set in form.  If it is not set a routine is run to generate a new foo and populate form.  If foo was already set then that value is used to populate form.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$var = isset ( $_GET ['var'] ) ? $_GET ['var'] : null;
$foo = isset ( $_GET ['foo'] ) ? $_GET ['foo'] : null;

echo "var is $var\n"; // correctly echos $_GET['var']

if ($var === $foo) {
    echo "POST foo seen\n"; // does not fire, condition not met
}

echo "var is $var\n"; //
```

Comment: What I intend here is the equivalent of "If post['foo'] is defined set $var to its value otherwise do nothing";  I have never seen it fail like this before.

Comment: if you just want to know if its defined `isset ( $_GET ['foo'] )` is all you need